# npm gives EOF reached while doing npm install or build from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, npm, next.js, dockerfile

I have one Next.js application which I Dockerize and run it on cloud provider. This was working fine for months but suddenly it started failing with error:

```
Step 8/10 : RUN npm run build-$BUILD_TIME
 ---> Running in 242287b65d1c

 > app-ui@0.1.0 build-dev
 > env-cmd -f env/.env.dev next build

 Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
 This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
 You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
 https://nextjs.org/telemetry

    Creating an optimized production build ...
    unexpected EOF
```

This either happens during `npm build` or `npm install`. But when I re-run it it runs successfully.

Below is my Dockerfile:

```
#Base Image
FROM node:18-alpine

#Pass the env
ARG BUILD_TIME
ENV BUILD_TIME=$BUILD_TIME

RUN mkdir -p /usr/app/
WORKDIR /usr/app/

COPY ./ ./

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build-$BUILD_TIME

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start-$BUILD_TIME"]
```

What I thought was I was doing `npm install` in Jenkins file as well and also in Dockerfile. Thinking this might be issue as it's happening twice I removed it. But still no luck.